# Java-TCL (tclblend) JDBC connection authentication error when used in different java Processes

Tags: java, jdbc, tcl

I am trying to run several processes that connect to a DB, perform some operation and then finishes it.

My code looks like this

Java calls the script using Process

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = r.exec(expectPath+" "+expectScriptPath+" "+ticket);        
SessionLogger sysout = new SessionLogger(logger,p.getInputStream());
sysout.start();           
SessionLogger syserr = new SessionLogger(logger,p.getErrorStream());
syserr.start();           
try {
   return p.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
   log.error(e.getMessage(),e);
   return -1;
}
```

TCL script calls a java method

```
set inputData [ java::call myPackage.TCLDriverWrapper pullNextInputData $ticket ]
```

Java code creates a jdbc connection, performs a simple query and closes the connection

```
private static LegacyDriverTaskInputData pullNextInputData(String token) throws Exception {
    Connection conn = null;
    try{
        conn = new TCLDriverWrapper().getConnection();
        QueryRunner run = new QueryRunner();
        ResultSetHandler<LegacyDriverTaskInputData> rsh = new BeanHandler<LegacyDriverTaskInputData>(LegacyDriverTaskInputData.class);
        LegacyDriverTaskInputData inputData = run.query(conn,"select * from mytable where id = ?",rsh,Long.valueOf(token));
        return inputData;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    } finally {
        DbUtils.close(conn);
    }
}
```

where

```
private Connection getConnection() throws Exception{   
    String driver = "...";
    if (driver == null || driver.trim().length()==0) {
        throw new Exception("...");
    }
    Class.forName(driver);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("user", MyConfiguration.getProperty("javawrapper.user"));
    props.put("password", MyConfiguration.getProperty("javawrapper.password"));
    return DriverManager.getConnection(MyConfiguration.getProperty("javawrapper.jdbc"), props);
}
```

One thing I've noticed is that when I trigger just one Process at a time, everything works fine.

But if I try to run 3 Processes at the same time (each one in its own thread) I get an error like this

```
Processing java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:498)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:620)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:169)
    at (...)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.send(DataPacket.java:210)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetOutputStream.flush(NetOutputStream.java:230)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:321)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:268)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:190)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:107)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:124)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:80)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1137)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:350)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOSESSKEY(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:407)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:416)
    ... 19 more
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:498)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:620)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:169)
(...)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at tcl.lang.reflect.PkgInvoker.invokeMethod(PkgInvoker.java:128)
    at tcl.lang.JavaInvoke.call(JavaInvoke.java:304)
    at tcl.lang.JavaInvoke.callStaticMethod(JavaInvoke.java:217)
    at tcl.lang.JavaCallCmd.cmdProc(JavaCallCmd.java:74)
    at tcl.lang.AutoloadStub.cmdProc(Extension.java:119)
    at tcl.lang.Interp.callCommand(Interp.java:1266)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.send(DataPacket.java:210)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetOutputStream.flush(NetOutputStream.java:230)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:321)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:268)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:190)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:107)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:124)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:80)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1137)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:350)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOSESSKEY(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:407)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:416)
    ... 19 more
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
```

It seems to me that something is not de-allocating some object properly, but I am not sure if it's on the java side, or if it's in the TCL side. Also, I don't know if TCL shares objects for different processes (does not make sense to me).

Any clue is welcome.

Code runs in Linux.

Comment: Sharing objects between _processes_ would be extremely unlikely. That's enormous voodoo. (Giving each process a delegate that reaches into the shared space would be more practical, but nobody bothers with that sort of thing for DB connections.)

Comment: That's what I've thought too @DonalFellows... :-(

Comment: Your database might be busy with work in another thread or may have reached it's max connections.  Look for variables you can configure in the db driver for max connections, connection wait time, etc.  There might be issues with read connections vs write connections.  Try opening readonly handles if possible for the select.  You might also want to monitor connection and close times in your threads to see if the db can only be accessed one at a time.